# How to copy a file from one git branch to another and save as different file?

Tags: git

I'd like to copy a file from one git branch to another but save it as a different filename. I know I can do this to copy it over with the same name. Is there a way to rename during the checkout?

```
git checkout otherbranch myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
git show otherbranch:myfile.txt > myfile2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

let's understand with an example: if you want to copy the ***index.html*** file from the master branch to develop branch with different file name then

step-1: checkout to develop branch

```
git checkout develop
```

step-2: copy file from master to develop branch

```
git show main:index.html > new_index.html
```

step-3: add this new file

```
git add .
```

step-4: commit file

```
git commit -m "message"
```

step-5: and push file

```
git push
```